# How does redirecting a subdomain to a new domain affect the original root domain

Tags: redirects, subdomain, redesign

Domain A currently has a subdomain B. Subdomain B is being redesigned and launching on its on domain C.

1. Should the redirects be created to Domain C individually or at the sun domain level within GoDaddy to redirect the entire subdomain B to new domain C? Owner of new domain C cannot get ownership of subdomain B.
2. What happens to the authority of Domain A when you put in place a redirect on the subdomain B to point to domain C? Both domain A and subdomain B have a DA of 19 according to ahrefs.
3. What will happen to the SEO of both domain A and new domain C once launched separately assuming nothing else changes on the sites?
4. Would you move the subdomain B to be a subdirectory of domain A, let Google reminded the site and then transfer to domain C, or would you go straight from subdomain B to new domain C with a redirect?

Trying to get third-party opinions on this situation and how it will impact each site individually once launched as two separate sites A and C.

Comment: If I was the owner of Domain C and was relying on content via a redirect that I did not control, I would run away...fast.

Answer (score 1):

This is an opinion, not a guarantee.   There are a lot of variables, including hidden ones only known to Google.

1. If there is a 1:1 page mapping between B and C there is virtually no difference between redirecting the entire subdomain B and new Domain C.  If the content maps to different pages, individual mapping is really required.
2. Domain A authority should not be heavily affected by the redirects.   If anything it will benefit over time if there is linking from C back to A because main domains generally (at least historically) tend to get more "google juice" then subdomains.
3. Subdomain will gradually pick up some of the juice from B (but not all of it). Domain A should be largely unaffected unless it was very closely tied in with B and not C
4. I'd go straight to C.  The answer may vary a little depending on the credibility of site A and how relevant the content of site C.  That said, a lot of the SEO juice is on a per page basis rather then a per domain basis.